# C# WPF check if button image has updated before updating again

Tags: c#, wpf, image, border

I'm working on making a memory game in C# using borders with images and changing their source. Changing the first source works correctly, however after the second flip I call a function to check if they match before flipping them to a correct or hidden image. I've been having an issue with the second image because the events I've tried call before the function has exited so the second image only shows the hidden image. Is there an event I can call to check if the image has loaded before exiting?

```
//border mousedown event
private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //flip the image over
        Border picBorder = sender as Border;
        picBorder.IsEnabled = false; //disable the border so they can't click it again
        int index = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(picBorder.Name, @"\d+").Value); //get border #
        BitmapImage car = new BitmapImage(carImages[index]);
        picBorder.Child = new Image { Source = car};
        picBorder.IsEnabled = false;
        //Storing border locations for checking later
        borderLocations[currentCarsFlipped] = picBorder;
        currentCarsFlipped++;
    }
```

Once CurrentCarsFlipped == 2, I need to check if there is a match. Currently, I have checkWin() which looks like it will work, but is hard to debug when you can only see 1 image for every 2 clicks

Answer (score 0):

use a Boolean variable , 
False if not updated and true after update, then you can check

Comment: What would the event be for updated? I've tried having it set to currenctCarsFlipped as a delegate after the function is done but I get the same outcome. I tried looking up an image updated one at MSDN to no avail.